# Add custom UIButton to UIKeyboard's accessory view for a UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

I need to add a camera button to a `UIWebView`'s keyboard accessory view toolbar (the one that already has the "Back|Next" and "Done" buttons).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a better way to do it, but one solution for the moment would be to destroy the bar and recreate it like so :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *aRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aURL];
    [web loadRequest:aRequest];
    [self.view addSubview:web];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)removeBar {
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
        // iOS 5 sticks the UIWebFormView inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIPeripheralHostView"].location != NSNotFound) {
            for (UIView *subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView in [possibleFormView subviews]) {
                if ([[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIWebFormAccessory"].location != NSNotFound) {

                    UISegmentedControl *nav = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Previous",@"Next", nil]];
                    nav.momentary = YES; 
                    nav.frame = CGRectMake(5, 8, 120, 30); 
                    nav.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
                    nav.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.25 alpha:1];
                    [nav addTarget:self action:@selector(navigate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

                    UIBarButtonItem *pictureBtn =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Picture" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(takePic:)];

                    UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
                    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)];

                    NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexButton,pictureBtn,flexButton,doneButton, nil];
                    [(UIToolbar *)subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView addSubview:nav];
                    [(UIToolbar *)subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView setItems:buttons];

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then, you have to implement the previous, next and done function again. But it's not the hardest part.

Comment: I've looked at both examples and they simply show to to create a new acessory view. I want to use the default one that shows up with a uiwebview but just add one button. A camera button that will allow a user to use the camera to scan a barcode. How do I add the button to the existing setup?

Answer (score 0):

there is an easier way to do this.

Keep your keyboard notification in your `viewDidLoad`

After that all you will need is the following method:

```
-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notif
{
    NSArray *array = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];

    for (UIWindow* wind in array) {
        for (UIView* currView in wind.subviews) {
            if ([[currView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
                for (UIView* perView in currView.subviews) {
                    if ([[perView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIWebFormAccessory"]) {

                        UIBarButtonItem *doneBttn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyBoard)];

                        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [(UIToolbar *) perView items]];

                    [arr addObject:doneBttn];

                    [(UIToolbar *) perView setItems:arr];
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have basically taken the original prev/next buttons from the UIWebFormAccessory and added a done button to the end of it, but you can add what ever buttons you want to this.

Some may think this shouldn't be implemented in `-(void)keyboardDidShow:` because you are changing the UI after it displays on screen, but so far I haven't noticed any issues with this. (only tested in simulator)

Hope this was useful!