# iOS use UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad in UIWebView form input

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview

I want to show the decimal pad with a '.' in the left corner used by native apps in a cordova based app.

[image]

I have seen a lot of threads using private APIs etc. but I want a solution that would go for app store submission. Any help is appreciated.

**I have already tried something from  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961103/uikeyboardappearance-in-uiwebview)  thread.**

Below is my modification,

```
@protocol TSPingPong <NSObject>
- (void) ts_pong: (id) sender;
@end

@interface NSObject (TSPingPong)
@end
@implementation NSObject (TSPingPong)
- (void) ts_ping: (id) sender
{
    if ( [sender respondsToSelector: @selector(ts_pong:)] )
    {
        [sender performSelector: @selector( ts_pong: ) withObject: self ];
    }
}
@end


@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(keyboardWillAppear:)
                                                 name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object: nil];

    NSString* html = @"<br><br><br><form action=''> " \
    "First name: <input type='text'><br> " \
    "Last name: <input type='text'><br>" \
    "<input type='submit' value='Submit'> " \
    "</form>";

    [_webView loadHTMLString: html
                     baseURL: nil];
}

- (void) keyboardWillAppear: (NSNotification*) n
{
    // the keyboard is about to appear!
    // play pingpong with the first responder so we can ensure it has a keyboardAppearance method:

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction: @selector( ts_ping:) // added via category extension
                                               to: nil                  // to: the first responder
                                             from: self                 // "sender"
                                         forEvent: nil];
}

- (void) ts_pong: (id) sender
{
    // sender is the first responder.  Happens to be undocumented "UIWebBrowserView" in this case.

    // if it doesn't have it's own keyboardAppearance method then let's add one:
    if ( ![sender respondsToSelector: @selector(keyboardAppearance)] )
    {
        Method m = class_getInstanceMethod( [self class], @selector( keyboardAppearanceTemplateMethod ) );

        IMP imp = method_getImplementation( m );

        const char* typeEncoding = method_getTypeEncoding( m );

        class_addMethod( [sender class], @selector(keyboardAppearance), imp, typeEncoding );

    }

    if ( ![sender respondsToSelector: @selector(keyboardType)] )
    {
        Method m1 = class_getInstanceMethod( [self class], @selector( keyboardTypeTemplateMethod ) );

        IMP imp1= method_getImplementation( m1 );

        const char* typeEncoding1 = method_getTypeEncoding( m1 );

        class_addMethod( [sender class], @selector(keyboardType), imp1, typeEncoding1 );

    }
}

- (UIKeyboardAppearance) keyboardAppearanceTemplateMethod
{
    return UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
}


- (UIKeyboardType)keyboardTypeTemplateMethod
{
    return UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
}
```

I am able to get the keyboard appearance to be dark but not the keyboard type which I desire.

Other threads and answers that I have seen so far but no results,

[How the default keyboard comes up when user taps in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961369/how-the-default-keyboard-comes-up-when-user-taps-in-uiwebview)

https://www.aerych.com/blog/2012/04/29/uiwebviews-uikeyboards-and-uitoolbars-oh-my/

[How to set a custom keyboard for UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781122/how-to-set-a-custom-keyboard-for-uiwebview)

[Add custom UIButton to UIKeyboard's accessory view for a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658300/add-custom-uibutton-to-uikeyboards-accessory-view-for-a-uiwebview)

https://github.com/dcorbatta/CKWebView

Comment: There are a ton of private APIs that will be approved in app store submission...

Comment: I have already seen a few but none worked well for me, can you please help me with a working one.

Comment: Try searching for "Xcode UIWebView decimal point in number pad"

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog None of the private API's work now.

Comment: @satheeshwaran any luck ?

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet Yes I did use a another UITextField to super impose on top of the <input> and moved the textfield whenever the page was scrolled etc. Then when keyboard is resigned I take the text out of the textfield and set it to the input tag.

Comment: @satheeshwaran i tried writing a new one https://github.com/mrchandoo/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard , still has one issue when the user closes the app and opens again he decimal button is vanished. do you mind checking it once ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your html string

```
<input type="tel"></input>
```

or

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"></input>
```

Comment: Dude type=tel brings up telephony keyboard, I specifically wanted decimal key. That's the whole point of the question. FYI I have tried these long time back.

Comment: Did you try the second option, with pattern = "[0-9]."

Comment: Yes that will just bring up alphanumeric keypad but not allow alphabets. Was not helping.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new plugin for this:
https://github.com/mnill/cordova-custom-keyboard

Comment: This approach uses a invisible textview which will not show the cursor. I need the cursor.

Comment: FYI I have tried this approach already, anyways thanks for the help!