# Cordova Application - Html Input Text with UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable / ASCII Capable

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm building a iOS cordova application that requires only `UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable` keyboard type only for html input type text, this is to prevent Chinese characters at the input.

Understands that this can be achieved at iOS native `UITextField` by setting keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable`.

Also understand that I'm able to prevent Chinese characters using javascript regex.

But what I'm looking for is to prevent keyboard switching via QuickType.

Do let me know of anything code required for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to change the keyboard type of my cordova app, referencing from a question at [iOS use UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad in UIWebView form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038710/ios-use-uikeyboardtypedecimalpad-in-uiwebview-form-input)

Here is the code,

```
NSString* UIClassString = [@[@"UI", @"Web", @"Browser", @"View"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString* UITraitsClassString = [@[@"UI", @"Text", @"Input", @"Traits"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
    return UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    // return UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
});

for (NSString* classString in @[UIClassString, UITraitsClassString]) {
    Class c = NSClassFromString(classString);
    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(c, @selector(keyboardType));

    if (m != NULL) {
        method_setImplementation(m, newImp);
    } else {
        class_addMethod(c, @selector(keyboardType), newImp, "l@:");
    }
}
```

Code need to be run at app start, or before the keyboard being shown.

This post another problem (Posted a question here [Cordova Application - Event Listener for before keyboard show / open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626406/cordova-application-event-listener-for-before-keyboard-show-open)). For other html input type such as `tel` , `number` , `email` and so on. The keyboard will be defaulted to `UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable` only.

You might need to have an event listener that listens to keyboard being shown and detect the element type, and change the keyboard type accordingly. Under this code

```
IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
    return UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    // return UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
});
```