# Cordova Application - Event Listener for before keyboard show / open

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying to change my keyboard type based on html input type `text` , `tel` or `email`.

I have manage to change the keyboard type using cordova plugin, here is the code.

```
NSString* UIClassString = [@[@"UI", @"Web", @"Browser", @"View"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString* UITraitsClassString = [@[@"UI", @"Text", @"Input", @"Traits"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {
    return UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    // return UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
});

for (NSString* classString in @[UIClassString, UITraitsClassString]) {
    Class c = NSClassFromString(classString);
    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(c, @selector(keyboardType));

    if (m != NULL) {
        method_setImplementation(m, newImp);
    } else {
        class_addMethod(c, @selector(keyboardType), newImp, "l@:");
    }
}
```

Manage to detect the element that cause the keyboard to show by using iOS's `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and adding an event listener that get active element using `document.activeElement`

Below is the code

Native:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];


- (void)onKeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note{
   [self.commandDelegate evalJs:@"cordova.fireDocumentEvent('keyboardWillShow', null, true);"];
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('keyboardWillShow', function() {
    let element = document.activeElement
    let type = _.get(element,'type')
    if(_.isEqual(type,'text')){
        changeKeyboardType('text')
    }else if(_.isEqual(type,'tel')){
        changeKeyboardType('tel')
    }       

}, false);
```

Based on the solution written, the keyboard is being shown before the keyboard change happens, so the question would be.

Is there any 'before keyboard show' event listener for javascript?

Comment: Refer to this stackoverflow answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242457/6536335

Comment: This might also help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24303517/6536335

Comment: I'll try on the first solution first, hope is works, cause I did try document.addEventListener('click') before this, but the keyboard opens before changing.

Comment: The focus event is call in an asynchronous manner. The keyboard still shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to change the keyboard by firing some javascript to get active element type and changes the keyboard type accordingly instead.

I can't seems to modify the keyboard type via `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` event as it is too late.

Here is my code on changing the keyboard type based on active element type,

```
NSString* UITraitsClassString = [@[@"UI", @"Text", @"Input", @"Traits"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

IMP newImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _s) {

    NSString *script = @"document.activeElement.type";
    NSString *type = @"";
    if ([self.webView isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
        type = [(UIWebView*)self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
    }

    if([type isEqualToString:@"text"]){
        return UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    } else if([type isEqualToString:@"tel"]){
        return UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapableNumberPad;
    }

    return UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
});

for (NSString* classString in @[UITraitsClassString]) {
    Class c = NSClassFromString(classString);
    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(c, @selector(keyboardType));

    if (m != NULL) {
        method_setImplementation(m, newImp);
    } else {
        class_addMethod(c, @selector(keyboardType), newImp, "l@:");
    }
}
```